# Dear SO user, please stop with this "emphasis mine"

Tags: discussion

To my dear co-users,

when you quote the standard of a language, we *know*<sup>1</sup> the emphasis is yours, added to pinpoint the few words replying to the question. No need to make it explicit.

---

**Edit**: [ From your reactions, I conclude I am the only one who the "emphasis mine" bothers. I won't delete the question since it has an answer, and I'll learn to live with it (or maybe write a greasemonkey filter to remove those mentions). ]

---

#### Example

**Question**

> What is Stack Overflow?

**Answer**

According to Stack Overflow's [about page](https://stackoverflow.com/company),

> Founded in 2008, **Stack Overflow is the largest, most trusted online community** for developers to learn, share their knowledge, and build their careers. More than 50 million professional and aspiring programmers visit Stack Overflow each month to help solve coding problems, develop new skills, and find job opportunities.

(emphasis mine)

---

(I know I'm off-topic, hopefully not *too much* off-topic (emphasis mine))

Comment: Actually, I *don't* always know that the emphasis wasn't in the original.

Comment: If it doesn't alter the meaning, why have it at all? Of course it alters meaning - by giving emphasis to something that wouldn't have it otherwise.

Comment: And even if you are right (which I think you aren't), what do you propose we do about it? How should SO fix that? Ban the string "emphasis mine"??

Comment: Aren't those basic citation rules? When one emphasizes a cited text, one is supposed to note that the emphasis was added.

Comment: @ModusTollens More specifically, anytime you alter a quotation in any way, you need to indicate what is an alteration, other examples being `[...]` to indicate an omitted section, or a changed pronoun to the actual noun due to the context being missing.

Comment: Academic citation standards demand that you cite truthfully and indicate any changes made to the text, that includes changes to emphasis or major changes to formatting.

Comment: You can also avoid the decision of whether or not to say "emphasis mine" by just not bolding anything in the quote. If someone can't detect the relevant portion of a small block of text, it's not likely to do anything for them even if you do point it out.

Comment: Experienced SO users tend to assume that other C++ programmers always have a copy of the C++ standard within reach.  Accessible in a matter of seconds, followed by a careful comparison between the quote and whatever standard version their current compiler adheres to.  It is not an accurate assumption.

Comment: Ah, yes, the 5 armed programmer.  Types really fast too :)

Comment: Emphasis doesn't change meaning?  I've seen the example "I never said she stole my money".  Try emphasizing each word in turn and re-evaluating the meaning of that sentence.  In any event, if you edit a quote you should very much leave an indicator.

Comment: From the same section of the site, what if you were quoting the health and wellness benefits description from https://stackoverflow.com/company/work-here, for example?

Comment: @YSC well exactly, if we are talking about standards, adhering to the standard way of quoting stuff should be preferred. A quote is an unmodified C&P of some other material. If there is any modification in the quote, standard is to show it in one way or another.

Comment: I dislike "Emphasis mine" as well. Perhaps using more neutral "Emphasis added" could work as a compromise.

Comment: Please don't put answers or meta-(meta-)content in the question - you've accepted the answer, that is sufficient. You could also write up your own answer if you wish.

Comment: And I've explained why in a comment. You stop putting responses in a question.

Comment: it works the same way on Meta as it does on the main site. Answers don't belong in the question. There's never a need to explain in a question why you don't delete it. Not deleting a question is the *normal* state of affairs and does not require any explanation. If you *really* feel that you need to make some follow-up remarks, either post a comment or do so in an answer.

Comment: Why? What is going on here? Is it really that distressing to find out that people disagree with you?

Comment: @YSC Hey there. Please be aware that this is a shared place. Nobody gets to "express myself the way I intend". We are all bound to the same rules, and we don't get to have exceptions for our specific cases. I, for one, find that this question is very useful, and gives a much needed framework for further discussions. Please do not delete it, or deface it. Hang in there, it's worth it.

Comment: Also, fwiw, if really you need to express your own conclusion, you can add it as an answer instead of editing it in your question. It would probably have garnered a few upvotes too.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question since it's completely opinion-based and no discussion have emerged from it.

Comment: "a greasemonkey filter to remove those mentions" ❤

Answer (score 58, accepted):

This is just people using academic citation standards. I think that's a good thing.

**Emphasis can actually change the meaning of a text**, and when citing truthfully you have to indicate that it was or wasn't you that made the emphasis.

There is no need for people to be less precise in their citing.

Comment: Doubly so with (often more casual) online text, where emphasis is sometimes intended to stand for tone. You don't want to quote in a way that misrepresents the original author.

Comment: @YSC SO is supposed to be a canonical reference. It's _very important_ that our posts have a high quality. High quality includes proper citation, especially since it's so easy and otherwise unobtrusive. How annoying is the "emphasis mine" really for you?

Comment: Another thing to note is although it is not required in the CC BY-SA version we use it is suggested that we show that we have modified the source we are quoting and in the latest version it is actually required: https://wiki.creativecommons.org/wiki/License_Versions#Modifications_and_adaptations_must_be_marked_as_such

Comment: I can see a need for less precise citing. *Emphasis mine* is mostly noise. SO's goal is to reduce noise, so this is in direct conflict with SO's goals. And there is the argument that the amount of noise created is not justified by the number of accidental changes in meaning due to emphasis where readers read the *emphasis mine* note which caused them to check the original text which avoided them being mislead. I'd even say that is sufficiently obscure to be negligible.

Comment: Actually, removing the "emphasis mine" would be completely unfair to the original citation. When citing a particular part of documentation, you may want to put into light a specific part of it for the reader, because you know said reader have problem with a specific part of a general problem. Not saying that you are putting the emphasis there, is like saying the original writer(s) put it themselves. That is completely inappropriate.

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier Assuming everyone agrees that having emphasis without *Emphasis mine* is totally surprising, why exactly is it bad to imply the original writer(s) put the emphasis there? All that was done is emphasize which part is particularly relevant to a specific situation, thus improving the quote. Who is getting hurt/mislead/otherwise disadvantaged by it?

Comment: @nwp Nobody says anything about being surprising, I say that it is misrepresentation. For instance, if you were to cite me, I'd be quite set back if you were to add emphasis at some place where I did not intend to do it. For instance, if you were to cite "This is **completely inappropriate**", it would put words and intent in my mouth. It would not in any way "improve" the quote, quite the contrary, actually. As for your question, everyone reading it would be mislead, thinking that I was finding it much more inappropriate than I actually do.

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier So your point is that "This is **completely inappropriate**"-FélixGagnon-Grenier hurts your feelings while "This is **completely inappropriate**"-FélixGagnon-Grenier (emphasis mine) does not. And you further think that enough people feel the same way that adding those 2 words makes enough of a difference to justify the noise. Did I get that right?

Comment: @nwp Yes, you could reduce it to that.

Comment: It is really difficult to evaluate this situation for someone who doesn't feel hurt by someone emphasizing a quote or feeling saved seeing "Emphasis mine". I guess I'll have to take your word for it that I am the uncommon type of person here and try to remember not to hurt people by accident.

Answer (score 10):

> To my dear co-users,
>
> when you quote *the standard of a language*, we know the emphasis is yours, added to pinpoint the few words replying to the question. No need to make it explicit.

What about quoting other things, such as your own statement? Shall I make it explicit then, so I don't look like I'm putting words in your mouth (or, should I say, *changing your tone*, since I'm not at all altering the words that were actually said)?

Comment: @YSC You are not the only one. It annoys me too and I fail to see the value and harm of omission. @ BoltClock I still think objectively it never happens that emphasis changes the meaning significantly and only after reading "emphasis mine" do people notice, then check the original and safe themselves from being deceived. This is a feeling problem. Many people have a strong feeling that you must never misquote and adding emphasis without saying so is misquoting. The actual harm done is irrelevant, it's a matter of principle/culture/convention/religion, so you are arguing the wrong point.

Comment: @YSC Actually, it's the other way around. If you feel your emphasis doesn't change anything, stop wasting my time and leave the original quote unchanged.

Comment: @nwp It is _not_ a "feeling problem". Adding "emphasis mine" is part of citation rules. Period.

Comment: @nwp: You're right, our culture values honesty and good faith on part of the quoter, and integrity of content. Any problem with that?

Comment: You are still missing that some people see it as completely honest and faithful to emphasize quotes. Quoting in itself means you cherry-pick some information that is relevant to the situation. You want to additionally give a bit of context because it's useful so you add some surrounding text. And then you do cherry-pick level 2 and emphasize the core message. For me there is absolutely no dishonesty or bad faith here. For you obviously an unquestionable rule has been broken. Instead of essentially writing "Duh!" you should explain that rule and why it is so important.

Comment: The rules are there not to prevent people from cherry-picking and altering their quotations; they are there to ensure that the author of the content that's being quoted doesn't get implicated for something they didn't say, and to keep the one quoting them accountable for any changes they *do* make by making them be upfront about them. (That's not to say that a quoter couldn't then just quote something verbatim and state that they altered the text when they really didn't, but I don't know what anyone would gain from doing that.)

Comment: @nwp No no no. You don't cherry pick someone else's words (or emphasis). You can use them to make or emphasise a point in your own words instead. It has nothing to do with honesty or faith. It's also not about unquestionable rules being broken or "feelings". It is common courtesy to not put emphasis in other people's mouth.

Comment: I don't know why this even needs to be discussed. Putting "emphasis mine" or "emphasis added" _is_ common practice. Can't you just ignore it instead of expecting others to _not_ use common practice?

Comment: It needs to be discussed because this common practice violates the SO principle of reducing noise. It has now been established that the value of the common practice is seen as higher by the community than the harm of the noise. My takeaway is "Add 'Emphasis mine' when applicable because otherwise people get angry". It's not ideal, but it works for now.

Comment: @nwp: If indicating which parts of someone else's quotation you changed is noise, then so is formatting the quotation as a quotation, because these things are mandatory when quoting. You might as well just never quote other people's words, then you won't have to deal with any of this, since it makes you so uncomfortable.

Comment: @nwp One last remark from me: I wouldn't get angry if I'd notice a missing "emphasis mine", but I would assume the poster to not know how to cite and would probably do the same as here: point out how citing is done.

Comment: Unrelatingly, hairy shet. It took me all of three days, seven rereads and the emphasis from @Boltclock to realize the question is about quoting *standards*. You bet emphasis changes, or clarifies, meaning.